# Perl split and throw away the first element in one line

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, split

I have some data that should be able to be easily split into a hash.

The following code is intended to split the string into its corresponding key/value pairs and store the output in a hash.

**Code:**

```
use Data::Dumper;

# create a test string
my $string = "thing1:data1thing2:data2thing3:data3";

# Doesn't split properly into a hash
my %hash = split m{(thing.):}, $string;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

However upon inspecting the output it is clear that this code does not work as intended.

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
    'data3' => undef,
    ''      => 'thing1',
    'data2' => 'thing3',
    'data1' => 'thing2'
};
```

---

To further investigate the problem I split the output into an array instead and printed the results.

**Code:**

```
# There is an extra blank element at the start of the array
my @data = split m{(thing.):}, $string;
for my $line (@data) {
    print "LINE: $line\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
LINE:
LINE: thing1
LINE: data1
LINE: thing2
LINE: data2
LINE: thing3
LINE: data3
```

As you can see the problem is that `split` is returning an extra empty element at the start of the array.

---

***Is there any way that I can throw away the first element from the split output and store it in a hash in one line?***

*I know I can store the output in an array and then just shift off the first value and store the array in a hash... but I'm just curious whether or not this can be done in one step.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`my (undef, %hash) = split m{(thing.):}, $string;` will throw away the first value.

Comment: No. Unless the data is so very predictable that every key looks like `data\d` this is a ridiculous solution

Comment: For the question "Is there any way that I can throw away the first element from the split output?" I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: If the data is so predictable then it is best just to write `my %hash = ( thing1 => 'data1', thing2 => 'data2', thing3 => 'data3' )` in the first place

Answer (score 4):

I'd alternatively suggest - use `regex` not `split`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = "thing1:data1thing2:data2thing3:data3";

my %results = $string =~ m/(thing\d+):([A-Z]+\d+)/ig;
print Dumper \%results;
```

Of course, this does make the assumption that you're matching 'word+digit' groups, as without that "numeric" separator it won't work as well. 
I'm aiming to primarily illustrate the technique - grab 'paired' values out of a string, because then they assign straight to a hash.

You might have to be a bit more complicated with the regex, for example nongreedy quantifiers:

```
my %results = $string =~ m/(thing.):(\w+?)(?=thing|$)/ig;
```

This may devalue it in terms of clarity.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but for what I am trying to do it is much more complicated and split maintains clarity much better than a regex would.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't always apply. But for many scenarios it does, simply because you can discard record separators, linefeeds etc.